# How to declare a Static Readonly List?

Tags: c#, list, struct, readonly

I have a structure and I want to have a static readonly list of this type.
In the readonly, the structure properties (HexCode, Name) aren't found. Making them public doesn't change anything.

Here is the structure declaration:

```
public struct FixedDataStruct
{
    string HexCode;
    string Name;
}
```

And here is the List:

```
private static readonly List<FixedDataStruct> myList= new List<FixedDataStruct>
{
        { HexCode = "12", Name = "Chenger" };
};
```

Comment: The two members of your struct are private, try making them public. Additionally, when posting questions like "what am I doing wrong", make sure to post enough information about **why** you think you're doing something wrong, such as compiler errors, exceptions, incorrect results, etc.

Comment: You are missing the `new`operator, you have a `;` that shouldn't be there. All in all, you should read the documentation for the collection initialization syntax

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen public fields on a struct?  That can't be safe.

Comment: @ParrishHusband Yeah, they should be readonly properties

Comment: @ParrishHusband Agreed on that, but I started with the most obvious problem, the lack of a clear problem description. There's plenty of issues here to go around.

Comment: As @CamiloTerevinto said, there's some other pieces missing. To make the code compiler a `new FixedDataStruct` would have to be added in the right spot, and the semicolon removed. That, plus making the members public, will make the code compile. It isn't **good** code, but it compiles, which I understood the question to be about.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Added the error I got and I tried to make it public, doesn't change a thing... neither adding new

Comment: There is no trace of your changes in your question. Since I got it to compile I can only assume you added the bits in the wrong places. Can you please update the question so we don't have to guess at what you did?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The question mentions the problem clearly now (didn't before) which was that HexCode and Name weren't found. I picked an answer that helped solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, and what I meant was that the question still has code that declares them as public. If you make them public, and also add the `new FixedDataStruct` before the `{` inside the collection declaration, then it compiles. That is, after making the fields public, this compiles: `private static readonly List<FixedDataStruct> myList = new List<FixedDataStruct> { new FixedDataStruct { HexCode = "12", Name = "Chenger" } };` (I also removed the semicolon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about?

```
private static readonly List<FixedDataStruct> myList = new List<FixedDataStruct>
{
    new FixedDataStruct("12","Chenger")
};
```

And

```
public struct FixedDataStruct
{
    public FixedDataStruct(string hexCode, string name)
    {
        HexCode = hexCode;
        Name = name;
    }

    string HexCode;
    string Name;
}
```

Comment: It would be much better if `HexCode` and `Name` where public readonly properties instead. Or if `private` is intended, `private` added and followed proper camel case naming.

Answer (score 2):

HexCode and Name are not found because they are fields of FixedDataStruct, but you are assigning them as if they were members of an anonymous object within the List object.  You have to create an instance of FixedDataStruct first, add it to the list, and assign its fields:

```
public struct FixedDataStruct
{
    public string HexCode;
    public string Name;
}

private static readonly List<FixedDataStruct> myList = new List<FixedDataStruct>() { 
    new FixedDataStruct() { HexCode = "12", Name = "Chenger" }
};
```

Comment: They are fields, not properties. The code you've shown will also construct the list first, then construct a new FixedDataStruct value, assign its fields, and then add it to the list.

Comment: OP called them properties.  Regardless, the point is irrelevant to the question asked, which is why HexCode and Name are not found.  I have answered that question.

Comment: `but you are assigning them as if they were properties of the List object`, no, the OP's not doing that. They are trying to assign those properties to an anonymous object. Also, it doesn't matter how the OP called them, they are still fields. Fields and properties are very different.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to reference the anonymous object, and to call them fields instead of properties.  The code remains unchanged.